# Is this an acceptable UI design decision?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface, anti-patterns

OK, while I'm on record as stating that StackExchange UI is pretty much one of the best websites and overall GUIs that I have ever seen as far as usability goes, there's one particular aspect of the trilogy that bugs me.

For an example, head on to http://meta.stackoverflow.com .

Look at the banner on top (the one that says "reminder -- it's April Fool's Day depending on your time zone!").

Personally, I feel that this is a "make the user do the figuring out work" anti-pattern (whatever it's officially called) - namely, instead of making your app smart enough to **only present a certain mode of operations in the conditions when that mode is appropriate**, you simply turn on the mode full on and put an explanation to the user of why the mode is on when it should not be (in this particular example, the mode is of course displaying the unicorn gravatars starting with 00:00 in the first timezone, despite the fact that some users still live in March 31st).

The Great Recalc was also handled the same way - instead of proactively telling the user "your rep was changed from X to Y" the same nearly invisible banner was displayed on meta.

So, the questions are:

- Is there such an official anti-pattern, and if so,m what the heck do i call it?
- Do you have any other well-known examples of such design anti-pattern?
- How would you fix either the SO example I made or you your own example? Is there a pattern of fixing or must it be a case-by-case solution?

Comment: You know, it's displaying regardless of your personal time zone because the unicorns do, too.

Comment: Unicorns can fly at speeds of over 9000 miles an hour; they respect no time zones.

Comment: Unicorns sometimes eat people, and then are eaten in turn by other people. Because after all, who doesn't love a man in unicorn?

Comment: @mike - I meant displaying unicorns AND the banner only on April 1st local, thus eliminating the need for the banner's weird wording about time zone.

Comment: BTW, people, please be serious. I know the unicorn gravatars were a joke, but I meant this as a serious design question

Comment: @DVK: what, you want me to make my bad joke an actual answer?

Comment: @MusiGenesis - are we talking about the fourth kind of love? (if you don't know the joke, google for "And finally there is love for our country, Soviet Union"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of this anti-pattern ought to be **Beware Of The Leopard**, after this exchange from [HH2G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

> '...You hadn't exactly gone out of
>   your way to call attention to them had
>   you? I mean like actually telling
>   anyone or anything.' 
>  'But the plans
>   were on display...' 
> 'On display? I
>   eventually had to go down to the
>   cellar to find them.'
>  'That's the
>   display department.'
>  'With a torch.'
>   'Ah, well the lights had probably
>   gone.' 
> 'So had the stairs.'
>  'But look
>   you found the notice didn't you?'
>   'Yes,' said Arthur, 'yes I did. It was
>   on display in the bottom of a locked
>   filing cabinet stuck in a disused
>   lavatory with a sign on the door
>   saying "Beware of The Leopard".'